# Calling Add on List in ExpandoObject throws RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I usually let Visual Studio break on CLR exceptions. But now I am facing something really weird; the following **does work**, but throws an exception that seems to be caught internally in .NET:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();

obj.list = new List<object>();
obj.list.Add(new { }); // throws RuntimeBinderException
```

Exceptions usually mean that something bad happened. Is there anything wrong with the code? Or is this just a weird little implementation detail that can be ignored?

Comment: How do you know exception thrown and caught internally? You saw first chance exception?

Comment: How do you get the exception I don't get anything.

Comment: Go to debug, exceptions and check CLR.